# Referring to matrices with index

Tags: matrix, assignment, indexed-variable

For exampe I have two matrices, with index 1 and 2

```
Mat[1] = ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}]
Mat[2] = ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}]
```

I wanna assign new value with

```
 Mat[1][[1, 1]] = 1
```

But get error

```
 Set::setps: Mat[1] in the part assignment is not a symbol.
```

But

```
Mat[1][[1, 1]]
```

gives the correct answer, i.e. $0$.

Question: How to correctly assign a value to a matrix with indices?

Comment: I think the only way to do this is with the function `Symbolize` in the Notation package. See the [Notation tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html).

Comment: `ReplacePart[Mat[1], {1, 1} -> 1]`

Comment: Instead of using a function Mat you could use an array: Mat= {ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}], ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}]}; Mat[[1,1,1]]=1